# Why is $\mu \overline \mu=p$ not possible if $p$ is not split in $K$ and does not divide $Q,D$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ with discriminant $D<0$. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal in $\mathcal{O_K}$ . For $\rho \in \mathfrak{a},Q \in \mathbb{N}$ it holds $\mu \overline \mu\equiv \rho\, (\text{mod}\,\mathfrak{a}Q\sqrt{D})$. Why is $\mu \overline \mu=p$ not possible if $p$ is not split in $K$ and does not divide $Q,D$?

I think $p$ can only be inert, so there are no ideals with norm $p$ but how does this bring me further?

Comment: Your notation is very confusing. What do you mean by "$\equiv\rho(\mathfrak a Q\sqrt{D})$"?

Comment: this should mean $\mu   \overline \mu \in \rho+ \mathfrak{a}Q\sqrt{D}$.